# the this pointer set by Object(this) != this

Tags: c++

the constructor for my engine constructs audio, video and input objects with a pointer to itself (this). However when I debug, I see all the classes I construct's enginePtr is not the same as the value of this provided by the debugger.

When I peek inside, I see for example, the enginePtr of pRender has different values than the engine. Most of them are set to NULL, which causes rendering to crash.

Here is my engine constructor:

```
cEngine::cEngine( int flag ) {

    if ( !al_get_system_driver() ) {

        this->isRunning = true;

        al_init();

        // Uses DirectX by default, uncomment ALLEGRO_OPENGL for OpenGL.
        if ( flag == OPENGL_WINDOW || flag == OPENGL ) al_set_new_display_flags( ALLEGRO_RESIZABLE | ALLEGRO_OPENGL );
        else if ( flag == DIRECTX_WINDOW || flag == DIRECTX ) al_set_new_display_flags( ALLEGRO_RESIZABLE );
        else if ( flag == OPENGL_FULLSCREEN ) al_set_new_display_flags( ALLEGRO_FULLSCREEN | ALLEGRO_OPENGL );
        else if ( flag == DIRECTX_FULLSCREEN ) al_set_new_display_flags( ALLEGRO_FULLSCREEN );

        this->display = createDisplay( "Motherload C++", -1, -1, 640, 480 );

        srand( ( unsigned ) time(0) );

        pCam    = new cCam( this );
        pIO     = new cIO( this );
        pMap    = new cMap( this, setPoint( 50, 50 ), setPoint( 13, 20 ) ); // 13, 20
        pPlayer = new cPlayer( this );
        pAudio  = new cAudio( this );
        pRender = new cRender( this );
        pEvents = new cEvents( this );

    }
}
```

cRender constructor:

```
cRender::cRender( cEngine* pEngine ) {

    this->pPlayerLoc    = pPlayerLoc;
    this->BLACK         = al_map_rgb(30, 100, 200);
    this->needsRedraw   = false;
    this->pEngine       = pEngine;

    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    splitImages();
    //this->font = al_load_font( "C:/resource/gisha.ttf", 24, 0 );
    //this->img = al_load_bitmap( "C:/resource/rock.png" );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing conceptually wrong with what you're attempting... must be a small implementation detail.  Can you show us the constructor of one of these classes (cCam, CIO, cAudio or whatever...?)

Comment: This shouldn't compile either, `pReander = new cRender( (this );` is syntactically uncompilable.

Comment: really, how so, pRender is a cRender*

Comment: @Milo: look again at the matching parenthesis

Comment: no that was a typing error, i fixed it

Comment: That looks ok.  There's probably some other operation that's overwriting it.  You could ensure no code does that accidentally by chaning cRender::pEngine to a cEngine& and initialising it in an initialiser list.  But, you've probably got some memory corruption, using a pEngine pointer after it's freed etc.. - use breakpoints or debug trace to check cRender at the end of construction, then periodically until you find corruption, then "binary-search" in on whatever's causing it.

Comment: My only comment is that pPlayerLoc will not be modified in the cRender constructor. I don't see anything wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unlikely. Your code seems logically fine to me. Instead or relying on debugger, try to print out the value of 'this' and whatever you stored in pRenderer. Sometimes, with optimization flags debuggers do not show the values of variables properly.